# When post data HttpURLConnection gives 500 interval server error?

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection

I'm using httpurlconnection for connect web-service. I try to send `json` data to body->raw but give me 500 interval error.

```
StringBuffer chaine = new StringBuffer("");

URL url;
try {
      JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
      jsonParam.put("password", password);
      jsonParam.put("email", email);              
      url = new URL(urls[0]);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
      connection.setRequestProperty("ApiKey", "ApiKey");
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
      printout.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
      printout.flush ();
      printout.close ();

      connection.connect();
      Log.w("tag",connection.getResponseCode()+" "+connection.getResponseMessage());
      InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                 chaine.append(line);
             }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
}

     content = chaine.substring(0,chaine.length());
```

Comment: This is a server problem. Do you have access so you can investigate logs?

Comment: not this time. Our web developer not here now.

Comment: Leos Literak  is right this is related to some issue at web service , This is happen because there must be something missing at web end

Comment: but in postman is work correct.ss http://www.imgim.com/screenshot2015-07-31at161529.png ss  http://imgim.com/image/screenshot2015-07-31at161512.png

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110736/http-1-1-500-internal-server-error-in-retrofit-post-method-android